# In Intellij ,Class files from 2 Different projects (created in different directories) interfere with each other

Tags: intellij-idea, multiple-projects

My Source code: 2 different branches from same repository. Both have  80% same code. Packages also same. But 20% classes are different in both branches. Its because of different features being developed in these branches.
My Intellij version is 2018.2.7 Community Edition

1. I cloned the repository in 2 different folders.
   consider first one:    C:\SourceCode\myRepo and move to branch1 from master
   consider second one:   C:\SourceCode\SecondCopy\myRepo and move to branch2 from master
2. Now I create 2 different projects in IntelliJ. One from C:\SourceCode\myRepo, Second from C:\SourceCode\SecondCopy\myRepo.
3. I build first project using git bash for windows using simple 'mvn clean install' command. (outside Intellij). Open Intellij. Run the application on Jetty. It goes good.
4. I have the second IntelliJ Project open as well in new Window. Now I build this second project in git bash using 'mvn clean install'(again outside Intellij). But as soon as I do that, the first project starts showing exceptions in code for the java classes which are not present in second project.
5. Even the application which was Already running using 'Run configuration of Intellij' in Jetty in First project, starts throwing class not found errors.
6. How can I resolve it and work on 2 projects having slightly different code but 80% same code, same packages etc. parallelly? What am I missing here? My intention is not to run Jetty parallelly. But to be able to compile these 2 projects independently and be able to Run Jetty in any one project anytime without interfering with other project.
   These projects are big projects and hence, I want to initiate build and run for one project. Till the time its up and running, I want to be able to work on the other one parallelly in a way that, this work after compiling/auto building in this project doesn't impact the other one where I just started the application.

It is killing my productivity. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone told me that... Its happening because I am using maven and after building, maven keeps the project libraries that it builds in local repository. So both the projects after building are trying to keep the jars in the same folder from where Jetty is reading as well. Hence there is interference.
I have not tried. but If I keep 2 separate local repositories for both the projects, it should solve, but with this all the dependencies will also be unnecessarily duplicated. So the solution is as mentioned by @Andrey is that I keep the maven coordinates separate for both the projects, so that 2 separate jars are created for both. Thanks Andrey.  I wont necessarily change maven coordinates for the all modules but for one where there is difference of code in both the projects. Hope this answer helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use different [Maven coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) for the projects.

Comment: how will maven coordinates help? Could you please elaborate?